# How to update existing past date value to newtime zone in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have many UTC timestamps.

My time is 7 hours ahead of UTC.

Question: how can I update time zones for past timestamps via PHP? For example, there is a value:

```
 2020-04-10 21:58:00
```

I would like to add +7 hours. The peculiarity in this case is that over time, the date also moves forward one day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why don't you save all datetime values in UTC and then adjust as per the current timezone of the user logged in. This will save you lots of problems down the line.

Comment: And what happens when your timezone is 6hours ahead of UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes for achieving your goal.

The static function `createfromdatestring()` of `DateInterval` can create an interval and you can add this interval with a `DateTime`.

```
$data = "2020-04-10 21:58:00";
$dateTime = new DateTime($data);
$interval = DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+7 hours');
$dateTime->add($interval);
print_r($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

#### Update

As  El_Vanja's suggestion, you can gain your requirement by using simply DateTime's `modify` function. This snippet also displays the same result.

```
$data = "2020-04-10 21:58:00";
$dateTime = new DateTime($data);
$dateTime->modify('+7 hours');
print_r($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: A simpler way is to directly modify the `DateTime` object `->modify('+7 hours')` without having to explicitly create and add an interval.

Comment: Sajeeb Ahamed, EI_Vanja - Thank you very much!!! 
It solved my problem